# teradata sql to insert from a volatile table to a permanent table

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement that I need to store a list of parameters. The parameters will be input as a csv file. They will be inserted into a table if not already existing. I have got a suggestion that I can import this data into a volatile table and use a sql query  like:

```
insert into table permvariables 
select * from tempvariables
minus 
select * from permvariables;
```

Where tempvariables is my volatile table and permvariables is my permanent table. Will this solution work? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `MINUS` simply use a

```
MERGE INTO permvariables AS tgt 
USING tempvariables AS src
ON tgt.pk_column(s) = src.pk_column(s)
WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT VALUES (src.pk_column(s), src.cola, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it because minnus wouldn't work in teradata sql or the merge is a more cost effective operation?

Comment: Of course MINUS/EXCEPT will work, same for INSERT SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS, but those need to access the target table twice. That's the main reason why Standard SQL implements MERGE.